# Tor wont connect all of a sudden

Tags: configuration, network-configuration, connection

Ive used tor regularily for along time, yesterday I installed Avast and Tor stopped working, I've remove avast and fixed all the settings I can think of but the log still says this:

```
1/28/22, 05:02:55.873 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
1/28/22, 05:02:55.873 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
1/28/22, 05:02:56.490 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
1/28/22, 05:02:57.375 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
1/28/22, 05:02:57.376 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9150
1/28/22, 05:02:57.396 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:02:57.457 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:02:57.457 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:02:57.520 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:02:57.520 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:02:57.520 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:03:49.470 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:03:49.470 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:03:49.470 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:03:49.470 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:04:26.505 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:04:26.506 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:04:26.506 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:04:26.506 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:04:26.506 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:05:57.312 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:05:57.312 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:05:57.312 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:07:29.439 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
1/28/22, 05:07:29.439 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Avast is caught by hand for selling user's data [here is the story](https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/antivirus-firm-avast-is-reportedly-selling-users-web-browsing-data/). Your Tor instance has not bootstrapped yet - because of the firewall activity. Make an exception for Tor or delete the Avast - I do recommend deletion

Comment: I've already removed Avast, I only installed as I picked up a piece of malware that was annoying me somewhere and wanted it gone, I've since removed, run a cleaning program to clean/repair the registry and even renewed all network data but I'm still having issues. When I run the windows diagnostic tool on the network it says that it does not have a valid IP configuration which I'm guessing is the issue with tor and Nord as well but even following all guides I can including releasing/renewing up and doing the full network reset it still keeps doing the same thing so I'm stumped.

Comment: If you will leave it for some time - are there *any* other log messages? Can you give it a shot for like 10 minutes and post a log here?